# nginx URL Redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, url

Excerpt from conf file

```
server {
    #HTTP SITE
    listen 80;
    server_name example.tv www.example.tv;

    #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    location / {
    return 301 https://example.tv$request_uri;
    }}
```

I'm looking to redirect https://example.com/?_=ANY_STRING_HERE to google.com

Is this achievable on nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name 'www.example.net';
    if ($arg__) {
        return 301 https://www.google.com;
    }
}
```

This will redirect `www.example.com/?_=Something` to `https://www.google.com` but `www.example.com/?_=` wont redirect, if you want so you'll need to use something like this: `if ($args ~ _)` but be aware that it will redirect everything that has `_` inside i.e. `www.example.com?param_1=5`

(I've found most information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988883/8745788))

Comment: Nope. Whenever a visitor types in www.example.net/?_=anything it should just redirect to google. I don't want it to search. The "?_=" is of importance here. Let me know if I sound ambiguous.

Comment: @Netizen110 I've updated the post properly now, check if it suite for you now.

Comment: @Netizen110 It means `?_=Something` but not `?_=` (You can use it with every param i.e.: `$arg_param1`, `$arg_id` ...)

Comment: Should I add the code located inside the server block after the end of 'location' curly brace?

Comment: I think you should add a new server block for the https (that listen on `433` port)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82575/discussion-between-netizen110-and-mattia).